# Searchview not working with onclicklistener

Tags: android, kotlin

The `searchview` is not working as I expected it to. When searching for a word using the `searchview`, the `onclicklistener` would not work, it would just `click` with no results. An example can be seen in the image below.(Image 2)

However when the `searchview` is empty the buttons work fine, it navigates to a new fragment.(Image 1)

I have been trying to find a way to solution, but I have no idea how to. I am using an `Arrayadapter`.

The images are at the bottom of the screen

**MainActivity.kt for the searchview**

```
lateinit var adapter:ArrayAdapter<String>
....

var user = arrayOf("Home","Dog","Cat","Hamster")
adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, user)

binding.categories.adapter = adapter

binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if (user.contains(query)) {
                adapter.filter.filter(query)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No Match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })
    val home = adapter.getItemId(0)
    val cat = adapter.getItemId(1)
    val hamster = adapter.getItemId(2)
    val dog = adapter.getItemId(3)
    binding.categories.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, ID ->
        when(ID){
            home ->{navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home2)
            }
            cat -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_cat) }
            hamster -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_hamster)}
            dog -> {navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_dog)
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.XML**

```
<!--searchview-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:queryHint="Enter Search"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"


        >
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
    <!--Listview-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/searchview_listitem"/>
```

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a customadapter.